# Creating new instance of Hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, jruby, jrubyonrails

I am quite new to Ruby, I am using HashWithIndifferentAccess for hash feature in Ruby. So my code is like:

```
def someFunction
    array_list = []
    some_array.each do | x |
        new_hash = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new
        // add entries to new_hash    

        array_list.push(new_hash)
    end

    array_list
end
```

Problem is: for each iteration I am initializing new hash, But if i do following, entry in array_list becomes empty:

```
def someFunction
    array_list = []
    new_hash = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new

    some_array.each do | x |
        // add entries to new_hash    

        array_list.push(new_hash)
        new_hash.clear
    end

    array_list
end
```

I don't want to initialize new hash for each iteration, Any solution for this issue ?

Comment: Why *don't [you] want to initialize new hash for each iteration*? You have to if you want to add multiple hashes to your array.

Answer (score 5):

> I don't want to initialize new hash for each iteration

Why not? What is the reasoning behind this? You have to, otherwise it cannot work.

If you don't create a new hash each iteration, you're pushing *the same hash* into the array every time. Each element in the array is the **same object**, sharing the same state. There is only *one hash*, when you clear it, all the references to that same hash are obviously also cleared, because they are all the same object.

> Any solution for this issue ?

Yes, you already have it: You need to create a new hash each iteration.